# Alternatives to == in dplyr::filter, to accomodate floating point numbers

Tags: r, filter, floating-accuracy

First off, let me say that I am aware that we are constrained by the limitations of computer arithmetic and floating point numbers and that 0.8 doesn't equal 0.8, sometimes. I'm curious about ways to address this using `==` in `dplyr::filter`, or with alternatives to it.

I am working on this piece of code that is functioning correctly. It filters the data accurately and then performs the interpolation as expected.

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(dplyr)

target_at = 0.5

# Create the data frame
data <- data.frame(
  t_ov_ri = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01),
  a_ov_c = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125, 0.03125),
  a_ov_t = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8),
  gi = rep("G5", 10),
  a0 = c(0.815055, 0.8463715, 0.8570045, 0.8839861, 0.9033134, 0.1116504, 0.2117479, 0.22943, 0.238598, 0.28524)
)

# Define the interpolation function
interpolate_a0 <- function(a_ov_t_low, a_ov_t_high, a0_low, a0_high, a_ov_t_target) {
  interpolation_factor <- (a_ov_t_target - a_ov_t_low) / (a_ov_t_high - a_ov_t_low)
  a0_target <- a0_low + interpolation_factor * (a0_high - a0_low)
  
  return(a0_target)
}

# Apply the interpolation function to the data frame for a_ov_t equal target_ac
data_sm <- data %>% filter(a_ov_t == target_at - 0.1)
data_lg <- data %>% filter(a_ov_t == target_at + 0.1)

interpolated_data <- data.frame(
  t_ov_ri = data_sm$t_ov_ri,
  a_ov_c = data_sm$a_ov_c,
  a_ov_t = rep(target_at, nrow(data_sm)),
  gi = data_sm$gi,
  a0 = mapply(interpolate_a0, data_sm$a_ov_t, data_lg$a_ov_t, data_sm$a0, data_lg$a0, rep(0.5, nrow(data_sm)))
)

# Find the min and max a_ov_c values for the interpolated data
a0_low <- min(interpolated_data$a0)
a0_high <- max(interpolated_data$a0)
```

If I modify `target_at = 0.7` (or other odd values), the filtering process fails to work correctly. Specifically, the code `data_lg <- data %>% filter(a_ov_t == target_at + 0.1)` does not include the values in `data` where `a_ov_t` is 0.8, despite the fact that `target_at + 0.1 = 0.8`, which is the same data type and value.

Understanding that these numbers don't equal each other because of tiny differences in how my computer stores them, I have currently solved the filtering issue with the following:

`data_lg <- data %>% filter(a_ov_t*10 == target_at*10 + 1)`

Now I'm wondering what better alternatives are there that will account for floating point numbers and filter my dataset correctly.

Comment: you should use `all.equal(abs(a_ov_t -target_at), 0.1)`

Comment: function `near` might be helpful to address the precision thing: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/near.html

Comment: When I'm looking for near-equality of floating-point, I often use `abs(val1 - val2) < 1e-9` where `1e-9` may be contextual (but should suffice for most things).